# Power Query: M Code for adding days (as column reference) to date

Tags: date, datetime, dateadd, customcolumn

Power Query: Table:'TableABC', with columns: [Todays Date],[Additional Days].

I want to create M Code to add [Todays Date] + [Additional Days].

I keep getting an error, because [Additional Days] is a decimal number- I think. Do I need some logic to convert it?

Tried: Date.AddDays(dateTime, days as number)

However, "days as number" is a column reference ([Additional Days])

Answer (score 0):

Convert to Duration! Got it. 
Basically the format of the column has to be in a Duration format to be added to any date.